# Azure Form Recognizer Billing

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer, azure-billing-api

I have .Net 6 API deployed on Azure with one method Recognize. This method calls Azure Form Recognizer endpoint with invoice PDF and its returning structured object. With this object, I do something on API and return the result to customer.
The Form Recognizer is listed under my Subscription in Azure. The fee for one call of Form Recognizer is a small amount.
I need this:
The customer (with his own subscription in Azure) calls my API with an OAuth token. The API calls Form Recognizer and I need the fee to be charged to the customer's subscription.

Is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not mandatory that the azure form recognizer service resource can be used within subscription. It can be accessed with endpoint and key secret (Regardless of subscription) from SDK.

You can use SDKs to access the form recognizer service resource. You can analyze files with form recognizer resource in customer's subscription from your API logic from API resource in your subscription.
Learn more about Form Recognizer SDK: [Use Form Recognizer SDKs or REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/how-to-guides/try-v2-1-sdk-rest-api?pivots=programming-language-csharp)